# Is the androidx.* necessary when I create a new project in Android Studio 3.4.2?

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

In my mind, androidx.* is optional for an Android project, I find that androidx.* is necessary when I update to Android Studio to 3.4.2.

See the Image. So androidx.* will be standard, right?

**Image**

[image]

Comment: You can still build a project without androidx, but all the new firebase and google play services libraries today require androidx for example. Then it will be the standard in short time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `AndroidX` is a major improvement to the original Android Support Library.
- Like the Support Library, AndroidX ships separately from the Android OS and provides backwards-compatibility across Android releases. `androidX` fully replaces the Support Library by providing feature parity and new libraries.
  [Here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx)
- If your app currently depends on the original Design Support Library, you can make use of the Refactor to `androidX` option provided by Android Studio. Doing so will update your app’s dependencies and code to use the newly packaged androidx.
- New `Design support library` requires `andriodX` migration too! You should consider using androidX for your future projects! [Here](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/)
- Add the library to the in your `build.gradle`(app-level) dependencies section:

  **implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:version'** [Latest Version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material)

Comment: is it any possible don't use AndroidX when creating a new project in Android Studio 3.4 at this moment?

Comment: Yes! Just don't check the checkbox when creating a new project. But you should consider using AndroidX.

Answer (score 0):

you can still make app absolutely..androidx is just a extension of the android library itself...so if you completely know android libraries,you can make any app,same as what androidx can,as the name implies,its a "support library" so without using it you can still make full blown app...again its a support library to make your life not worrying of compatibility for your app,but if your really know android programming,your dont need androidx.infact making app in android(not androidx)is better because you dont need transitions in the future same to what happen to those who rely on android support libraries..

Comment: androidx is a trend, it is recommended to use androidx instead of support libraries!

Comment: as you said it is a trend..just try to look at androidx itself,it all extends android alone...so if you know the work around in android,you dont need androidx just to make a full blown app..check all the dependencies its all still android.